# Arithmetic Recursion

Tags: recursion, scheme, arithmetic-expressions

I'm a beginner to scheme and I'm trying to learn some arithmetic recursion. I can't seem to wrap my head around doing this using scheme and producing the correct results. For my example, I'm trying to produce a integer key for a string by doing arithmetic on each character in the string. In this case the string is a list such as: '(h e l l o). The arithmetic I need to perform is to:

For each character in the string do --> (33 * constant + position of letter in alphabet)
Where the constant is an input and the string is input as a list.

So far I have this:

```
(define alphaTest
  (lambda (x)
    (cond ((eq? x 'a) 1)
          ((eq? x 'b) 2))))

(define test 
   (lambda (string constant)
      (if (null? string) 1
      (* (+ (* 33 constant) (alphaTest (car string))) (test (cdr string)))
```

I am trying to test a simple string (test '( a b ) 2) but I cannot produce the correct result. I realize my recursion must be wrong but I've been toying with it for hours and hitting a wall each time. Can anyone provide any help towards achieving this arithmetic recursion? Please and thank you. Keep in mind I'm an amateur at Scheme language :)

**EDIT**
I would like to constant that's inputted to change through each iteration of the string by making the new constant = (+ (* 33 constant) (alphaTest (car string))). The output that I'm expecting for input string '(a b) and constant 2 should be as follows:

1st Iteration '(a): (+ (* 33 2) (1)) = 67     sum = 67, constant becomes 67
2nd Iteration '(b): (+ (* 33 67) (2)) = 2213  sum = 2213, constant becomes 2213

```
(test '(a b) 2) => 2280
```

Comment: You've described what to do to each character of the string but not how to combine the results for each character to provide a final, single number.  Also, it would help if you described the expected result of `(test '(#\a #\b) 2)`

Comment: I updated the question. Thank's GoZoner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
(define position-in-alphabet
  (let ([A (- (char->integer #\A) 1)])
    (λ (ch)
      (- (char->integer (char-upcase ch)) A))))

(define make-key
  (λ (s constant)
    (let loop ([s s] [constant constant] [sum 0])
      (cond
        [(null? s)
          sum]
        [else
          (let ([delta (+ (* 33 constant) (position-in-alphabet (car s)))])
            (loop (cdr s) delta (+ sum delta)))]))))

(make-key (string->list ) 2) => 0
(make-key (string->list ab) 2) => 2280
```

BTW, is the procedure supposed to work on strings containing characters other than letters—like numerals or spaces? In that case, `position-in-alphabet` might yield some surprising results. To make a decent key, you might just call `char->integer` and not bother with `position-in-alphabet`. `char->integer` will give you a different number for each character, not just each letter in the alphabet.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply Ben! To answer your question, no I am not accounting for special characters in the string, only letters. Your code works, however I forgot to mention that I needed to keep updating the constant by setting it equal to the sum each iteration. I tried adding another argument to loop (x constant) and then when calling loop, add (* 1 sum) to pass as x, but it sees sum at 0 when doing that. How do I do it so I can pass the result of sum as the new constant?

Comment: Now I think I understand. In that case, you can calculate the sum using the current constant, and just pass the new sum as the new constant in all but the first iteration. I've edited the solution to illustrate. Or, if the constant should be the key for a zero-length string, then Ankur's solution is correct.

Comment: Thanks for updating your solution. What you gave me is very helpful and much appreciated. I am almost complete with this, but what I meant with the constant being updated is that I don't want the constant to be: new constant + sum, but rather just be new constant without adding itself to sum. I'll make this clear by updating my original question with the expected results.

Comment: Thank you so much Ben, you saved me a huge headache. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define position-in-alphabet
  (let ([A (- (char->integer #\A) 1)])
    (lambda (ch)
      (- (char->integer (char-upcase ch)) A))))


(define (test chars constant)
  (define (loop chars result)
    (if (null? chars)
        result
        (let ((r (+ (* 33 result) (position-in-alphabet (car chars)))))
          (loop (rest chars) (+ r result)))))
  (loop chars constant))

(test (list #\a #\b) 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution (in MIT-Gnu Scheme):

```
(define (alphaTest x)
  (cond ((eq? x 'a) 1)
    ((eq? x 'b) 2)))

(define (test string constant)
  (if (null? string) 
      constant
      (test (cdr string) 
        (+ (* 33 constant) (alphaTest (car string))))))
```

Sample outputs:

```
(test '(a) 2)
;Value: 67

(test '(a b) 2)
;Value: 2213
```

I simply transform the constant in each recursive call and return it as the value when the string runs out.

I got rid of the lambda expressions to make it easier to see what's happening. (Also, in this case the lambda forms are not really needed.)

---

Your test procedure definition appears to be broken:

```
(define test 
  (lambda (string constant)
    (if (null? string) 
    1
    (* (+ (* 33 constant) 
          (alphaTest (car string))) 
       (test (cdr string)))
```

Your code reads as:

- Create a procedure `test` that accepts two arguments; `string` and `constant`.
- If `string` is null, pass value 1, to end the recursion. Otherwise, multiply the following values:

  - some term x that is = (33 * constant) + (alphaTest (car string)), and
  - some term y that is the output of recursively passing (cdr string) to the test procedure

I don't see how term y will evaluate, as 'test' needs two arguments. My interpreter threw an error. Also, the parentheses are unbalanced. And there's something weird about the computation that I can't put my finger on -- try to do a paper evaluation to see what might be getting computed in each recursive call.